# Bad performance on Android Chrome when animating movement on elements with complex box-shadow and text-shadow in React

Tags: android, css, reactjs, google-chrome, animation

Fiddling with a small react application i experienced terrible performance when viewing it in chrome on an android mobile device. I narrowed it down to being related to movement animation on elements with glowing effects from box-shadow and test-shadow properties.

I've made an example where the performance issue can be observed by turning on border and number glow effect.

https://lueivind.github.io/chrome-android-animation/

I've tested on Windows Desktop Chrome and Edge, Android Mobile Edge and Firefox, Iphone Safari and Chrome. Just by observing, performance seems fine on all except for Chrome on Android.

Code is avaliable here;
https://github.com/lueivind/chrome-android-animation

Weird?

Comment: I appreciate that you provided a demo and source code since you were using a react project, but next time use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) and share the link, that way it's easier for us to test/modify the demo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that CSS keyframe animates on a layout property `left`.

```css
@keyframes translation {
    0%{
      left: 0;
    }
    100%{
      left: calc(100% - 11em);
    }
  }
```

When you want to have smooth performant animation, avoid layout properties since the browser has to recalculate element position in the document as well as if it moved other elements, for every 60fps. Instead, aim for animating [composite properties](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count) which are `opacity` and `transform`.

```css
@keyframes translation {
    0%{
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 11em));
    }
  }
```

This [article goes much more in depth](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering) in what happens in the browser when you animate. Here are list of [CSS properties](https://csstriggers.com/) to use/avoid when animating.

Comment: Thanks @CalebTaylor, your answer resolved the performance issue. Still weird though i think that it was only noticeable on android chrome, which I guess made me assume there was nothing wrong with my css. Still, valuable experience, thanks again.